# Update Menu on start

Tags: java, android, menu

I have a function which updates the menu. The problem is: this function should be called when application starts but in `onCreate()` it isn't possible because the menu wasn't create at this time so I get an exception.
Is there any other possibility to call this MenuUpdate nearly at the start?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: nullpointer exception, because menu wasn't created at the time where the function is called

Comment: Couldn't you just update it on the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function? I think it's the same. It's going to update once the user chooses to view the menu.

Comment: Or you could explicitly create the menu and then update the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android activity has a method `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` in which you can access menu items. To initiate call to this function you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. So the code to update menu in the activity's `onCreate(...)` method will look like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updateMenu();
} 

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Do update staff with menu instance
}

private void updateMenu() {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `onCreateOptionsMenu`, here is an example where some menu items are hidden during the creation:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, (android.view.Menu) menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    showOption(R.id.menu_edit);
    hideOption(R.id.menu_check);
    hideOption(R.id.menu_cancel);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function needs to update menu, call

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

in your activity class to refresh immediately.